# Papers on IEEE Xplore or ACM DL

Tags: publications, journals, conference, computer-science, ieee

**Background:** I am an undergrad student who took a CS elective.

My software engineering professor has asked us to review a bunch of research papers on certain topics in software development. **He specifically wants us to review papers only from IEEE and ACM Transaction papers or conference papers.**

I found a [paper](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/8780518) of interest in IEEEXplore. It says:

> Publisher: IEEE

at the top, but below the abstract, it says:

> Published in: 2018 Third International Conference on Informatics and Computing (ICIC)

I tried to find more about ICIC but could not figure out if this conference is affiliated to IEEE.

**My questions:**

- Does this count as an IEEE Conference paper?
- Can I safely assume that all papers available on IEEE Xplore or ACM Digital Library are published as IEEE transaction or conference papers, and ACM papers respectively?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does this count as an IEEE Conference paper?

Yes

> Can I safely assume that all papers available on IEEE Xplore or ACM
> Digital Library are published as IEEE transaction or conference
> papers, and ACM papers respectively?

I think so and will be surprised if that is not the case.

Comment: Please do edit your answer as not all ieee explore papers are transaction papers.

Comment: @Aymuos you're misinterpreting the sentence. The statement "all papers available on IEEE Xplore [...] are published as IEEE transaction or conference papers" does not imply that they are all transaction papers.

Comment: oh okay! Sorry about that!

Comment: Thanks @Wetenschaap! That is exactly what I want to say.

Answer (score 1):

You can safely assume that. Since these are specific to the publishing body itself. For instance:

- ScienceDirect for Elsevier,
- ACM Digital Library for ACM Journals,
- IEEE Xplore for IEEE related journals and conferences/proceedings,
- Springerlink for Springer Journals and Conferences/proceedings etc

Answer (score 0):

```
Does this count as an IEEE Conference paper?
```

Yes!

```
Can I safely assume that all papers available on IEEE Xplore or ACM Digital Library are published as IEEE transaction or conference papers, and ACM papers respectively?
```

Not all papers available on IEEE Xplore are transaction papers. **Transaction papers are only "transaction papers" and not conference papers.** I'm not entirely sure if this is correct but they can also be counted as "journal papers". Transaction papers are generally regarded as the highest quality papers in that field. Any accepted transaction paper will have the "transaction" as part of the transaction name on top of the paper.

**All ieee conference papers are publised on ieee explore.** Any paper on ieee explore is part of ieee (in form of a conference/journal/transaction etc.)

The same goes for ACM as well.

Here is a example of the "transaction".

[image]